# Mapping php to fcgiext.dll vs php-cgi.exe

Tags: php, iis-6, fastcgi

I seem to be able to run PHP scripts either by mapping `.php` to IIS directly by using `\PHP\php-cgi.exe` or through `\Windows\system32\inetsrv\fcgiext.dll`.

I can't tell the difference between the two methods, other than that by using `fcgiext.dll` you are given the option to set custom per site configuration for cgi.

Why shouldn't I map php directly to `php-cgi.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's massively slower.

fcgiext.dll runs the FastCGI add-in for IIS, which keeps a pool of PHP-CGI processes "hot" (i.e. running), and then feeds requests through them sequentially.

With the other configuration, for each request, a single process is started (which is not fast), processes that one request, and terminates.

Process startup is time consuming on Windows; FastCGI amortizes the cost of process startup/shutdown by running a few in parallel, pushing lots of requests through them, and then terminating them every (think it's something like) 1000 (configurable) requests.

Look up FastCGI on IIS6 for more information.

Comment: So should I set up a separate config section for each site or can I point every site to the same config section? eg "php:1=phpconfig" and "php:2=phpconfig"

Comment: I don't know; that seems more like a PHP question, which should be posted as a new question.

Comment: To answer my own question, using Process Viewer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653 a separate process is created for each site regardless whether they share the same fcgiext.ini config section.